# Can I keep multiple goods of 1 type if I have multiple warehouses?

Tags: harbour

In *Harbour*, the rules for the warehouse symbol state:

> When shipping goods, a player can keep 1 good of 1 type for each warehouse symbol they own.

If I have 2 warehouse symbols, can I keep 2 goods of 1 type? Or must I keep 1 good each of 2 different types?

Comment: @goldPseudo thanks for the new tag. Couldn't see a way to do that on mobile

Comment: The tag will be automatically reaped unless someone creates a tag wiki for it, or unless a second question is tagged with it shortly. Please consider doing one of these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Harbour FAQ on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1319084/harbour-faq):

> When using warehouses, how many goods can you store?
>
> You can keep up to the number of goods you have warehouse symbols. However, you cannot use warehouses to increase the amounts of goods to higher than they were before shipping.
>
> *Example: You ship two stone and four wood and have three warehouses. You can save two stone and one wood, one stone and two wood or three wood. You cannot "store" three stone since that is more than was shipped.*

Based on this, you are allowed to store multiples of the same type of good, you just can't store more than you currently have (i.e. no making things out of thin air.)